# How to store a texture in memory and render a small portion of it

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I have a texture that I would like to store in memory. Then I would like to render a portion of this texture onto an OpenGL context. I would like to know how to do this.

So far I've set up my vertex data.

```
GLfloat texture[] =
{
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,  // top rght
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0,      0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f,    0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,  // top left
};
```

I then go through the usual steps of creating a VBO, and using the OpenGL functions

```
GLuint indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 3, //First triangle
    1, 2, 3  //Second triangle
};

GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1,& VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texture), texture, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//position attributes
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
//colour attributes
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//TexCoord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindVertexArray(0); //unbind VAO
```

load and create a texture:

```
GLuint texture0;

int width, height;
unsigned char* image[1];

glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);//set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (usually basic wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
image[0] = SOIL_load_image("Textures/texture.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image[0]);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
```

I then use a while loop to activate the shader and then draw the texture. However want I now want to do is store this texture in memory and render only a small portion of it. Do I use a Renderbuffer object or a PBO, or is there some other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wanted to render of the portion of the loaded texture simply adjust your texture coordinates in a VBO accordingly.

Texture coordinates passed to the `texture(...)` function in a shader program map the bottom left corner as `(0,0)` and the top right corner as `(1,1)`. So if we would like to map only the top right corner of a texture to a flat quad, our texture coordinates would consist of `(0.5,0.5)`, `(0.5,1.0)`, `(1.0,1.0)`, and `(1.0,0.5)`.

---

Here would be the vertex and texture coordinate VBO data:

```
float[] vertices = {
      0.5,  0.5, 0.0,     // upper left triangle
     -0.5,  0.5, 0.0,
     -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,

      0.5,  0.5, 0.0,     // lower right triangle
     -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
      0.5, -0.5, 0.0
};

float[] textureCoords = {
     1.0, 1.0,
     0.5, 1.0,
     0.5, 0.5,

     1.0, 1.0,
     0.5, 0.5,
     1.0, 0.5
};
```

Once you have your data load `vertices` to a VAO as attribute 1 and `textureCoords` as attribute 2. Then your shader should look something like this:

Vertex Shader:

```
in vec3 vertex;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 interpolatedCoords;

void main(void) {

     interpolatedCoords = textureCoords;

     gl_Position = vertex; // You transform these coordinates or whatever you'd like here

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
in vec2 interpolatedCoords;

out vec4 out_color;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main(void) {

     out_color = texture(texture, interpolatedCoords);

}
```

That would be the most bare bones example of mapping some portion of a texture onto a simple 2D quad.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the answer I needed :]